# How to count multiple additions within a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a staffing spreadsheet that I need to put a total FTE into a cell. in some cases, there are multiple staff added to the cell but I need to count the headcount of staff allocated.

**Screenshot**

[image: screen shot]

in the row labeled 2D and column labeled OT the 2.89FTE is actually 3 physical staff working in. How do i count the 2.89 as 3 people?

I have tried TRUNC and count / countif but that is not accurate.

Comment: If your question is "how to round 2.89 up to 3", the answer is by using [`ROUNDUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/roundup-function-f8bc9b23-e795-47db-8703-db171d0c42a7). But without details about how you calculate 2.89 in the first place or about the rest of your spreadsheet, there is no way to tell if that is what you are after: 2.89FTE could also be achieved with 4, 5, etc actual people; no reason to think it is bound to be only 3 actual people.

Comment: The 2.89 can can be made up of 3 people working a combination of 0.79+1.05+1.05 = 3 physical people working different amount of hours. I have other reporting needs hence the reason for putting the FTE in but to work out if the ward is over staffed even or understaffed as per headcount.

Comment: If it;s people working 0.79 +1.05 + 1.05 it's not 3. Why 1.05? You're counting in the expectation of overtime in FTE calculation? That's not FTE, but Full Time Equivalent + Overtime, meaning you need somebody to cover to not have structural overtime. Also if somebody's working 0.79 FTE, you can't count it as 1 FTE, but 0.79.
But this makes me wonder what are the calculations behind the red numbers..

Comment: Sure ... `2.89 = 0.79,+1.05+1.05` but that tells us nothing about the logic of the sheet, does it? Should we understand the cell showing `2.89` in fact contains a formula summing 3 cells together? I get your expected result is 3 but I have no idea what your attempt resulted in nor what "*that is not accurate*" means here. Especially, an integer returned by a formula may be **right** or **wrong** but in no way **(in)accurate** (only non-discrete values such as floating-point numbers can be (in)accurate). I suggest you edit your question to include details.

Answer (score 0):

If your cells are input in this way:
=0.79+1.05+1.05
Which displays 2.89 in the cell, you can count the number of + characters in the formula then add 1.

You could do this by using

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(cell_ref))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(cell_ref),"+",""))+1
```

To handle blank cells, you could wrap this in an IFERROR statement, so that any #n/a error is counted as zero.

```
=IFERROR(LEN(FORMULATEXT(cell_ref))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(cell_ref),"+",""))+1,0)
```

Comment: That works but if I have no staff to allocate the cell is blank. Then as the cell is blank I gt a #n/a answer. How can I apply the formula to count the blank cell?

Comment: @steve Edited the original post showing how to use iferror function to handle #n/a